# What strings should I look for in /var/log/auth.log?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, authentication

I wrote a bash command to scan `/var/log/auth.log` for messages occurring on the current day indicating unauthorised access.  Currently it just fetches messages matching `BREAK-IN` and `unauthorized`.

What other strings should I search for in `/var/log/auth.log` to keep tabs on unauthorized access?

Here's the script for reference:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log|grep "$(date|awk '{print $2" "$3}')"|grep -E '(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)'
```

---

### Edit

Here's the amended command based on Justins suggestions and what I found through Google

```
grep "$(date|awk '{print $2" "$3}')" /var/log/auth.log|grep -E '(BREAK-IN|Invalid user|Failed|refused|su|Illegal)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for "Invalid user" which is thrown when someone tries to logon with an account that does not exist.  It will also throw up "Failed password" when you enter in an invalid password.

Also, you dont need to use cat to dump the file to grep.  Grep can already look at the file as its second option.  'Grep search-criteria /path/tp/file'

Comment: Thanks Justin, I had googled some answers actually and have amended the last grep string accordingly.  Thanks for the tip on `cat`, it's obviously time for bed ;o)